# PC/Browser program to manage cloud storage and FTP files?

Tags: windows, gratis, file-management, firefox, ftp

**Requirements (in order)**

1. Windows 8 *and/or* Firefox friendly
2. Free (or fits requirements after trial)
3. Dropbox integration
4. Connecting to non-local S/FTP servers (like Filezilla)
5. Google Drive integration

**Optional**

- Password-protected to enter program
- OneDrive integration
- Box.net integration

**Examples From Android**

- [ES File Explorer](http://www.estrongs.com/?lang=en)
- ["FX" File Explorer](http://android.nextapp.com/site/fx)

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific on your requirements?

Comment: At the very least, why not try your example Android programs on Windows though an emulator or virtual machine? At least until a suitable, native replacement appears.

Comment: Are you saying there is no windows alternative? I want a windows program, so i don't have to deal with emulators. I have a 22 inch screen and want to utilize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [NetDrive](http://www.netdrive.net/)

Pros:

- Supports Dropbox, Google Drive, OneDrive, and Box
- Runs on Window 8.1
- Can connect to FTP servers
- Integration into Windows Explorer
- Can pay via PayPal*

[It can also be used to access your Android phone's contents.](http://www.netdrive.net/airdrive/)

Cons:

- *non-free; 30-day trial, after 30 days you can only use one drive (ie. a single drive, and ***not*** OneDrive.)
- not password protected

Comment: Just to clarify... You mean one drive as in "a single drive"... Not " OneDrive"... Right?

Comment: @onebree Yep, a single drive. Edited for clarification :)

Comment: I would give it a try, but i hate having a taste of something i can't regularly have... I need at least one drive and one FTP support... Omg all the edits in making to my question!!

Comment: I chose this as an answer because (1) a longer free trial, (2) Expandrive limits to 20 minutes of use after trial, (3) i like how it integrates with windows, (4) i just saw that it connects to your phone...

Answer (score 0):

### [ExpanDrive](http://www.expandrive.com/expandrive)

- Windows (or Mac)
- Dropbox
- Google Drive
- S/FTP
- OneDrive
- Box.net
- *Many* more cloud servers
- Accepts PayPal
- $50
- 7-day trial

---

FYI: I found this via http://alternativeto.net/software/netdrive/ I did *not* explore the two Android apps so there could be other options out there.

Comment: After the trial, what features do you have?

Comment: Also, I checked the link you added, and no avail. Everything is either paid software or FTP only.

Comment: Based on the requirements you posted, it seems that if you are willing to spend $50 then it is a good program. But most of us are used to free or $25 software, right?

Comment: ... What does it include after the trial ends? Do you still have features?

Comment: It's not my program, of course, but the features look good. http://www.expandrive.com/expandrive

Comment: I'm on my phone, so I'm just typing as i go. I know you don't own it.... And from what i see, it doesn't explain post trial features... Like, does it let you have SOME features for free?

Answer (score 0):

**AirExplorer**

http://www.airexplorer.net/en/

Air Explorer supports: 
OneDrive, Google Drive, Box, Dropbox, Mega, Copy, Mediafire, Yandex, Baidu y WebDAV

- Direct management of your files in the cloud Optionally Air Explorer
- can encrypt your files when you upload them to the cloud
- Sets up multiple accounts from the same server
- You can synchronize folders between any cloud or your computer