# Are there any data and file storage systems which are Google Drive, Dropbox APIs or S3 for in house use?

Tags: file-synchronization, api, data, google-drive

Are there any data and file storage systems which are Google Drive, Dropbox or S3 compatible so programs and apps which use one or more of the three for file storage, sharing, syncing can store their data on in-house servers?

Comment: This question and its answers were focused on software for individual systems. https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/15037/pc-browser-program-to-manage-cloud-storage-and-ftp-files I get the feeling, however, that you are looking for software to run on the server to that the cloud storage is transparent to the users. Is that true?

Comment: @HunterHogan Yes that is true. Local networked storage that clients can store data on using Google Drive APIs is what I'm looking for.

Comment: So, you are looking for a third-party server implementation of the Google Drive API, right? I suggest you remove the mention of Dropbox, or make it another question which would be Dropbox-focused.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul The quesion was initially about realtime collaboration which I didn't explain well, but because the answers focused on file syncing and sharing I have created a new question http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/16475/lan-file-storage-systems-which-are-google-drive-realtime-api-compatible-for-real for the realtime api

Answer (score 2):

1. [ownCloud Enterprise Edition](https://owncloud.com/features/) supports Google, Dropbox, and more.
2. [Egnyte HybridCloud](https://www.egnyte.com/file-server/online-file-server-features.html) supports Google and some other services, but I don't think it integrates with Dropbox
3. [DriveHQ](http://www.drivehq.com/) proprietary system that only has WebDAV, no integration with Google or Dropbox but allegedly cheaper than Dropbox, and explicitly designed for servers

I *know* I saw another service that supported Google and Dropbox and was explicitly designed for server drive letters, but it's 4 am and I can't remember the name.

Answer (score 1):

There is an [open-source implementation](https://github.com/goodow/realtime-store) of Google Drive Realtime API, which provides native Android, iOS, Javascript client libraries. See also the [Web Playground](http://realtimeplayground.goodow.com/).

Comment: See this http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/16475/lan-file-storage-systems-which-are-google-drive-realtime-api-compatible-for-real

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I'm understanding the question fully (perhaps an example with Alice, Bill and Ted working thru what they actually want to accomplish?).

http://www.expandrive.com/ may be what Hunter is thinking of, and it's certainly a very handy tool for accessing ssh or cloud storage as though it's local.  It can be slow however..

I can see installing expandrive on one machine and having it sync to the cloud storage, while everyone in the corporate network just maps to that one machine.

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP is after. Reading the comments on the question itself: *Local networked storage that clients can store data on **using Google Drive APIs** is what I'm looking for.* "Using SSH" ≠ "Using Google Drive API".