# LAN file storage systems which are Google Drive Realtime API compatible for realtime mulltiuser app collaboration?

Tags: collaboration, api, google-drive

Some browse and mobile apps such as [Mindmup](https://www.mindmup.com/)  use the [Google Drive Realtime API](https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime) for realtime multiuser collaboration.

Are there any LAN based alternatives which support the Google Drive Realtime API to allow such apps work locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an [open-source implementation](https://github.com/goodow/realtime-store) of Google Drive Realtime API, which provides native Android, iOS, Javascript client libraries. See also the [Web Playground](http://realtimeplayground.goodow.com/).